# Dual problem of minimizing a quadratic objective function with an infinity norm inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In [Banerjee et al. (2008)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/banerjee08a/banerjee08a.pdf) the authors derived from (eq 4) :
$$\operatorname{min}_{y}\{y^TWy : \|y-S_j\|_{\infty}\leq \lambda \} $$
the dual problem (eq 5)
$$ \operatorname{min}_x x^TW^{-1}x -S_j^Tx+\lambda\|x\|_1$$
where $S_j$ is a vector, $W\succ 0$. I can't find this dual problem from the primal. I know that the dual of $\ell_{\infty}$ norm is $\ell_1$ but it didn't help me much.
Any idea ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is directly using Lagrangian duality. Adding an auxiliary variable $z = y - S_j$, your problem becomes:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{mininize} &\quad y^T W y \\
\text{subject to} 
  &\quad ||z||_\infty \leq \lambda \\
  &\quad z - y + S_j = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Using *only* the linear constraint for the Lagrangian, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(y, z; x) 
  &= y^T W y + x^T(z - y + S_j) \\
  &= y^T W y - x^T y + x^T S_j + x^T z
\end{aligned}
$$

Minimizing the Lagrangian above yields:
$$
\begin{aligned}
q(x) &= \inf_{y,z} \{ L(y, z; x) : ||z||_\infty \leq \lambda  \} \\
  &= \inf_y \{ y^T W y - x^T y \} + \inf_z \{ x^T z : ||z||_\infty \leq \lambda \} + x^T S_j \\
  &= \inf_y \{ y^T W y - x^T y \} - \sup_z \{ -x^T z : ||z||_\infty \leq \lambda \} + x^T S_j \\
  &= \inf_y \{ y^T W y - x^T y \} - \lambda \sup_z \{  (-x)^T (\tfrac{1}{\lambda} z) : ||\tfrac{1}{\lambda}z||_\infty \leq 1 \} + x^T S_j
\end{aligned}
$$
The infimum can be computed by comparing the gradient to zero, since it is a minimization of a convex quadratic function, and it yields $$-\frac{1}{4} x^T W^{-1} x$$
The supermum is precisely the definition of the dual norm, and thus it yields 
$$||-x||_1 = ||x||_1$$
So the dual problem is:
$$
\text{maximize} \quad q(x) := -\frac{1}{4} x^T W^{-1} x - \lambda ||x||_1 + x^T S_j
$$
When cast as a minimization problem, it is *almost* what you wanted, up to the constant $\tfrac{1}{4}$ before the quadratic term. Since in the paper they only want to say something about the structure of the problem , and thus the constant is not really important, I believe that this small technical error does not make any different with respect to their claim in the paper.

Comment: thank you ! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Indeed, this is great. Adding the equality constraint to isolate the nonlinearity really is the key. I could have done that with the conic form too, but I like the fact that this simplifies the standard approach too.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find it easiest to use conic formulations to get to the dual form. In this case, we have:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & y^TWy \\
\text{subject to} & (y - S_j, \lambda) \in \mathcal{K}_{\ell_1}
\end{array}
where $\mathcal{K}_{\ell_1}$ is the epigraph of the $\ell_1$ norm, a cone. The Lagrangian is
$$L(y,x,s) = y^TWy - \langle (y - S_j, \lambda), (x, s) \rangle = y^TWy - (y-S_j)^T x - \lambda s$$
where $(x,s)$ lies in the dual cone $\mathcal{K}_{\ell_1}^*=\mathcal{K}_{\ell_\infty}$. The optimality condition on $y$ is $2Wy - x = 0$, or $y = \frac{1}{2} W^{-1} x$. So the dual function is
$$g(x,s) = \frac{1}{4} x^TW^{-1} x - \frac{1}{2} x^TW^{-1} x + S_j^T x - \lambda s = - \frac{1}{4} x^TW^{-1} x + S_j^T x - \lambda s$$
The dual problem is
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & g(x,s) = \inf_y L(y,x,s) \\
\text{subject to} & \|x\|_1 \leq s
\end{array}$$
Substituting, we have
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & - \frac{1}{4} x^TW^{-1} x + S_j^T x - \lambda s \\
\text{subject to} & \|x\|_1 \leq s
\end{array}$$
Eliminating $s$ would give us the closest result to the one offered. It is not clear to me why the authors chose to express the negative of the dual; the proper dual is necessarily a maximization.

Comment: Thanks ! It's really interesting to see this conic formulation

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt in finding the dual problem. You will notice that its formulation is slightly different from the one stated in the paper. This means that I might be doing something wrong in the derivation, however, I thought I should post this answer just to show one approach for finding the dual.

Expressing the primal problem as (with $S_j$ written as $s$ for clarity)

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize } & y^TWy\\
\text{subject to } & y-s-\lambda1\leq 0\\
& -y+s-\lambda1 \leq 0
\end{align}
$$
where $1$ is the all-ones vector, the dual problem can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
\text{maximize } & \inf_y \mathcal{L}(y,\mu_1,\mu_2)\\\
\text{subject to } & \mu_1\geq 0\\
& \mu_2 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

with optimization variables $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, where the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ equals

$$
\mathcal{L} \triangleq y^TWy + \mu_1^T(y-s-\lambda1)+\mu_2^T(-y+s-\lambda1).
$$

By standard differential calculus, it follows that $\mathcal{L}$ is minimized w.r.t. $y$, for $y=y^*=\frac{1}{2}W^{-1}(\mu_2-\mu_1)$, which leads to the explicit dual problem formulation

$$
\begin{align}
\text{maximize } & -\frac{1}{4}(\mu_2-\mu_1)^TW^{-1}(\mu_2-\mu_1)+s^T(\mu_2-\mu_1) -\lambda 1^T(\mu_2-\mu_1) - 2\lambda 1^T \mu_1\\
\text{subject to } & \mu_1\geq 0\\
& \mu_2 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

With the optimization variable transformation $\mu_2 = x + \mu_1$, the above can be written as (writing the objective as a minimization problem)

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize } & \frac{1}{4}x^TW^{-1}x-s^Tx +\lambda \|x\|_1 + 2\lambda \| \mu_1\|_1\\
\text{subject to } & \mu_1\geq 0\\
& x+\mu_1 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

Now, notice that $\mu_1$ affects only the last term of the objective function, which is clearly minimized for $\mu_1 = 0$. This, in turn, simplifies the dual problem as

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize } & \frac{1}{4}x^TW^{-1}x-s^Tx +\lambda \|x\|_1 \\
\text{subject to } & x\geq 0\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you ! It's a nice reformulation of the constraints